# How to write a PowerShell code to get the count of number of items from a SharePoint list based on a condition

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

In this SharePoint list there is a column named College. How do I retrieve the count of items who have been to that particular college using PowerShell script from that list

Comment: A simple google search provided me below link. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-do-a-CAML-Query-6f5260cf

Comment: Please do your own research before posting question

Comment: I applied the same thing in my code. I wanted to know if there is any keyword  to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PowerShell script for your reference.

```
$siteUrl="http://sp2013/sites/team"
$listName="CollegeList"
$college="College1"

$web = get-spweb $siteUrl
$list = $web.lists[$listName]
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$spQuery.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='College'/><Value Type='Text'>"+$college+"</Value></Eq></Where>" 
$items = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
write-host $items.Count
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps). It has the lot of extension powershell commands targeting SharePoint object. Below is the sample PnP Powershell commands returns you the count of list items from list based on the condition.

```
PS C:\ktskumar> $cred = Get-Credential
PS C:\ktskumar> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
PS C:\ktskumar> $itemsCount = Get-PnPListItem -List "Sample List" -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category'/><Value Type='Text'>SampleCategory</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
PS C:\ktskumar> $itemsCount.Count
```

WebURL: https://tenant.sharepoint.com
List: Sample List
FieldName: Category
FieldValue: SampleCategory

I hope this helps you to get the ListItems count.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the bit tricky one:**

$siteUrl="http://spsite/sites/team"

$listName="Test1"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential(Get-Credential)
Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.Title -Contains $listName} | Select-Object Title, ItemCount